# base64 encode in js and decode in python. Unicode issue

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, python-2.x

I have following string in js.

```
*"form-uploads/2015 Perry's Awärds Letter.jpg"*
```

It has a `ä` symbol.

When i encode it in js using btoa ( in chrome) i get following:
*"Zm9ybS11cGxvYWRzLzIwMTUgUGVycnkncyBBd+RyZHMgTGV0dGVyLmpwZw=="*

And when I try to decode it in python I get following:

```
In[16]: base64.b64decode('Zm9ybS11cGxvYWRzLzIwMTUgUGVycnkncyBBd+RyZHMgTGV0dGVyLmpwZw==')
Out[16]: "form-uploads/2015 Perry's Aw\xe4rds Letter.jpg"
```

So ä got lost, and if I try to decode that string for `utf-8` I get a error.

```
In[18]: base64.b64decode('Zm9ybS11cGxvYWRzLzIwMTUgUGVycnkncyBBd+RyZHMgTGV0dGVyLmpwZw==').decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 28: invalid continuation byte
```

How can `i` get a proper `utf-8` `ä` in python code after decoding?

Comment: `s.decode("base-64").decode("latin-1")` will do the same thing, you don't need to import a library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try latin1, it can't be utf8 because in utf8 there are no 1 byte chars with MSB set to 1 (like \xe4).

```
base64.b64decode('Zm9ybS11cGxvYWRzLzIwMTUgUGVycnkncyBBd+RyZHMgTGV0dGVyLmpwZw==').decode('latin1')
```

Also btoa is not working well with unicode in general:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#The_Unicode_Problem

Answer (score 5):

You need to decode with `latin1` encoding and then print the Unicode :

```
>>> print base64.b64decode(u'Zm9ybS11cGxvYWRzLzIwMTUgUGVycnkncyBBd+RyZHMgTGV0dGVyLmpwZw==').decode('latin1')
form-uploads/2015 Perry's Awärds Letter.jpg
```